# CSS - Undesired div staggering and text wrapping

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have an events listing page where the date is wrapped in a div for styling purposes. If the following code is left as is, the divs become staggered. Also, if the p content after the div is longer than a few lines, it wraps around the div. Is there an easy way to prevent this without encasing each listing in a div?

#### HTML:

```
<div class="date">Mar <span>28</span></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

<div class="date">Mar <span>29</span></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

<div class="date">Apr <span>6</span></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

#### CSS:

```
.date {
float: left;
width: 42px;
height: 40px;
padding-top: 2px;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: #ccc;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.date span {
display: block;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

There are problems with a few solutions:

Adding `.date + p { height: 42px }` means long lines of p content will overflow.

Adding `.date + p { min-height: 42px }` doesn't account for the text wrapping.

Adding `.date + p { margin-left: 50px }` would work if I didn't have a mobile version of the site which puts the p content underneath the div.

I also made a fiddle for this.
http://jsfiddle.net/9t48g/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.date {
    clear:left;
}
.date + p {
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aber100/qs8WC/

That should work if you can't change the html. Otherwise, I would use Nicole Sullivan's media object html/css for this layout.

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for, but how does this display in browsers that don't support `min-height`?

Comment: Min-height and the adjacent sibling selector (+) are supported in IE7 and greater. There is a IE6 hack for min-height too. If you have other browser compatibility concerns, you can check http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference or http://caniuse.com.

Answer (score 0):

For the 'staggering' problem, add `clear: left` to the CSS for `.date` - that will make each entry drop below the preceding floated content.

(Using `margin-left` to solve the wrapping problem seems very sensible - surely there's a way you can use that but omit it from your mobile site?  A media query, or a class on the body?)

Comment: Adding `clear: left` seems to make the divs fall out-of-sync with the paragraphs. They need to stay lined up horizontally. I will probably end up using `margin-left` and altering the media query to reflect the styling change. In which case I can probably use `min-height` to solve the staggering problem, but it isn't supported by older browsers. My CSS knowledge is somewhere in the early 2000's.